# Authorization callback URL GitHub

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, url, github

I'm beginning iOS developer. I create an application that uses GitHub authorization. When I register a new OAuth application in GitHub developer program I must enter Authorization callback URL. But I do not have any site for my app. What do I need to specify in this field?

Answer (score 3):

You can use deep linking.

you can read more about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/communicating_with_other_apps_using_custom_urls)

The deeplink will try to open the app or redirect to it. The web browser or `SFAuthenticationSession` will close the browser and call the completion hander where you can check for the response code without any implementation for the deeplink.

To add the deep link in the app you can this below:

- Select the project in Xcode navigator.
- then select your target that you want to add the deep link to it.
- select info from the top bar
- at the bottom open the URL Types
- add a name for the scheme

[image: add deeplink]

when you generate the URL for the oauth you can pass anything you want I just pass login in this example:

```
func getAuthenticateURL() -> URL {

    var urlComponent = URLComponents(string: "https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize")!

    var queryItems =  urlComponent.queryItems ?? []

    queryItems.append(URLQueryItem(name: "client_id", value: "YOUR_CLIENT_ID_HERE"))
    queryItems.append(URLQueryItem(name: "redirect_uri", value: "APP_SCHEME_GOES_HERE://login"))

    urlComponent.queryItems = queryItems

    return urlComponent.url!
}
```

Then when you need to login do this:

```
import SafariServices

var authSession: SFAuthenticationSession?

func authenticate(with url: URL, completion: @escaping ((_ token: String?, _ error: Error?) -> Void)) {

    authSession?.cancel()

    authSession = SFAuthenticationSession(url: url, callbackURLScheme: nil, completionHandler: { url, error in

        //get the token and call the completion handler
    })

    authSession?.start()
}
```

or use  `ASWebAuthenticationSession` the same way if you're on iOS 12

Comment: thank you for an answer! In Developer settings Github app I added this callback URL "APP_SCHEME_GOES_HERE://connect/github/callback" but return to the application still does not happen. What's wrong with this url?

Comment: Did you do the fist step and also replaced that with your own scheme name

Comment: Any success with this?

Comment: @zombie: Can I ask you some questions?

Comment: @Paul go ahead sure

Comment: @zombie: Thank you.
I'm developing an app for mac os, which should authenticate with github and then get some information.
I am using https://github.com/stleamist/BetterSafariView.

I have read the suggestions that have been proposed in this issue here so I did this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Frf30.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/t12pT.png

Am I doing it correctly?
What would be better to put in the `Homepage URL`?

Comment: @zombie: The code I'm using at the moment is this: https://pastebin.com/DtdtcqkD

Comment: @Paul I would suggest to create a full running app and share it with a question on SO or somewhere else. you can also take a Look at this [wwdc video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/516/?time=740) (btw I'm not sure what you mean by homepage)

Answer (score 2):

Using SFAuthenticationSession you can do something like this. On your App add **URLType**:

[image]

Then on GitHub 'Developer Settings' for your app, add **Authorization callback URL** like this:

[image]

This way, after you login and authorize, Git Hub will call back **//yourappname** and Safari will redirect it back to your app completing the flow.

Comment: Can I ask you some questions?